# Question regarding map_partitions in a dask.dataframe object

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have `pandas.DataFrame` object called `df`, and I want to interpolate its missing values via parallelization. This is what I do:

```
def func(df):
    return df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=1)


ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=8)
res = ddf.map_partitions(func)
res2 = res.compute()
```

The outcome is,

```
print(res2)
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
5    None
6    None
7    None
dtype: object
```

and

```
type(res)
dask.dataframe.core.Series
```

**Edit 1**
After following @mdurant suggestion, I've changed the function to this

```
def func(df):
    return df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

and now the result is the expected one.

However, I'm still having some newbie questions regarding this code. The benchmarks below show that the non parallel version is faster than the parallel one.

Non parallel:

```
%time df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=1, inplace=True)
Interpolating missing values.
CPU times: user 19.5 s, sys: 162 ms, total: 19.7 s
Wall time: 19.8 s
```

Parallel:

```
res = ddf.map_partitions(func)
%time res2 = res.compute()
Interpolating missing values.Interpolating missing values.
Interpolating missing values.Interpolating missing values.
Interpolating missing values.Interpolating missing values.
Interpolating missing values.Interpolating missing values.
CPU times: user 29.1 s, sys: 2.3 s, total: 31.4 s
Wall time: 26.5 s

res.visualize()
```

[image]

This interpolation is a row-wise operation (interpolation is in `row=1`), so any chunk(thread) show run without penalization (chunking happens between indices).

Comment: The `func` in **Edit 1** is the same as before.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is `inplace=True` - with this, the call to `interpolate` doesn't return anything, so the output of `func()` is None, and you get the results you see. Generally, Dask functions should return processed data rather than trying to change data in-place. Simply remove the keyword, and things will probably work.